# Run program from terminal with either stdinput or program input

Tags: python, input

I have a program called main.py

In main.py, I do lots of things, but what it all boils down to is asking for input.

When i run program from terminal, I want to both be able to run:

```
python main.py input_file.txt
```

... which would run through input_file.txt and read one line at the time.

I also want to be able to run:

```
python main.py
```

... which would cause terminal to accept input, one line at the time.

My current code in main for reading input is:

```
def start_engine(self):
    """Starts the Engine, meaning polling for input"""
    print("Enter one line for each image/group with format "
          "'type width height', or 'G i, i, ...'. Exit with 'Q'. \n")

    for line in fileinput.input():
        do_something_with_line(line)
```

Using fileinput.input() is working great for reading from a file, obviously. However, when I want to just run

```
python main.py
```

and manually enter input, I can never exit the input thing. It never actually reads my lines, I just write into a "dead console window"

How do I go about this?

Comment: Check the number of parameters in input by counting words separated by whitespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and easy solution to your problem is as follows:

```
import sys

if __name__ ==  "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        t = raw_input("Lets begin. Type something!!!: ")
        while t != "quit":
            print "You just typed " + str(t)
            t = raw_input("Type something: ")
            #do something
        exit()
    a = sys.argv[1]
    print "The system argument supplied is:" + str(a)
    #do something
    exit()
```

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

It's reading from standard input until that file closes, which is typically accomplished by typing Control-D at the start of a line.

Comment: Is there any way to use it so that it doesn't wait until the input is closed before returning lines? I don't see anything in the doc https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/fileinput.html

Comment: Hm, good point. Actually, it looks like it does if you hit Control-D after *each* line; two successive Control-Ds actually cause the iterator to close. (Which also means that `for line in fileinput.input():` is *not* the same as `for line in sys.stdin:` when no file names are in `sys.argv[1:]`.)

Comment: It seems to treat standard input as an infinite stream of non-empty files; it buffers the reads before beginning to return lines, and doesn't stop iterating until it encounters an empty instance.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty weird. It seems like it's trying to emulate perl's `while (<>)`, but doesn't quite get it right.